# Generic DataReader combined with Generic resultset processor

Tags: c#, generics, datareader

I am looking to solve the following issue using two generic entities, namely (and symbolically expressed), `GetItems<SomeReaderType>()` and `ProcessItems<SomeProcessorType>()`.

`GetItems<SomeReaderType>()` should create an object for each row in a `datareader`.

`ProcessItems<SomeProcessorType>()` should process each object created by the `datareader`.

My example does not include implementation because I would like to (and don't know how to):

1. Have the type of reader (CSV, Excel, ODBC, whatever...) indicated using some configuration file (? .ini ?) (in other words, a string ('EXCEL') would indicate the source of data .)
2. Have the type of processor SomeProcessor Type ('Executor', 'Documentor', 'Scanner', etc.) be determined in a similar fashion (config / .ini file).